# Cant access SharePoint 2007 Central Admin

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2007, central-administration

Everything was fine and accessible until this morning when I tried to open CA from server and I received below error, I can access the CA from my local PC or any other PC, its just the SharePoint server that have the issue.
Can you please help.

Regards [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to open CA from your local PC and you are not able to open CA from CA server - It looks like system administrators changed firewall policy and disallow browsing internet from servers.

Try to add your CA site into Local Intranet list. To do this:

1. Open Internet Explorer on CA server
2. Click on Internet Options
3. Click on Security tab
4. Add your site to Local Intranet list

Also you can try to browse your CA site by IP or localhost(if it was configured on IIS side)